# Password Protect XSSFWorkBook Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi

I need to password protect XSSFWorkBook. For HSSF, I am able to do it easily but the same implementation is not working for XSSFWorkBook.

I am using Apache POI 3.6 and 3.9 both. I mean I tried using both 3.6 and 3.9.

I guess I need to use POIFSFileSystem but can anyone guide me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Password Protect is supported by latest version of poi.

Please see http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html

Have tried the suggested method and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Base on [Apache POI - Encryption support](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) doc.

It is depend on file system, that mean `MS-Office 2003` or `MS-Office 2007`, etc..

The following program work in `MS-Office 2007`. Please, check the documentation

```
POIFSFileSystem filesystem = --> get your filesystem
EncryptionInfo encInfo = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem); 
Decryptor decryptor = new Decryptor(encInfo); 
decryptor.verifyPassword("your-password"); 
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(decryptor.getDataStream(filesystem))
```

Comment: This is for reading encrypted sheet..I want to encrypt sheet with a password.

Comment: Also, the above code says cannot instantiate Decryptor..Hence 3rd line is not working at all.

Comment: You probably have an old version of Apache POI then, try upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache POI we can read the password protected files, but their is no option to create the password protected files.

So try some other commercial library like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/).